# System is locked for inactivity even though that setting is turned off

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

I have my Brightness & Lock settings like this:

[image: B&L]

And this used to work like I wanted to - screens turned off after ten minutes, no password was required to start again.

However, since about a week or so - after installing some standard system update, I'm afraid I don't know which - whenever the screens are turned off, I need to input my password. I would like this turned off, as in my ignored settings.

I'm not sure what information helps, but I use double monitors, and I also have Nvidia's custom drivers installed.

Thank you.